# Fetching multiple GET requests API using React and assigning variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have been working on a program which calls multiple APIs makes the results viewable on the app and then I also have to keep track of the results in order to compare them for a later feature. So far I have tried many methods and this was worked best but the issue I am having with my current code is that only one response is visible on the app

```
class GetRequest extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        gemBTCask: null,
        gemBTCbid: null,
        gemETHask: null,
        gemETHbid: null
    };
}

async componentDidMount() {

    fetch('https://api.gemini.com/v1/pubticker/ethusd')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ gemETHask: data.ask }))
        //.then(data => this.setState({ gemETHbid: data.bid }));
    fetch('https://api.gemini.com/v1/pubticker/ethusd')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ gemETHbid: data.bid }));
    fetch('https://api.gemini.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ gemBTCask: data.ask }));
    fetch('https://api.gemini.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ gemBTCask: data.ask }));

}

render() {
    const { gemBTCask } = this.state;
    const { gemBTCbid } = this.state;
    const { gemETCask } = this.state;
    const { gemETCbid } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="card text-center m-3">
            <div className="card-body">
                gemini BTC bid: $: {gemBTCbid}
            </div>
            <div className="card-arm">
                gemini BTC ask: $: {gemBTCask}
            </div>
            <div className="card-ear">
                gemini ETC bid: $: {gemETCbid}
            </div>
            <div className="card-leg">
                gemini ETC ask: $: {gemETCask}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Look into `Promise.all`...

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few typos in your code... compare to this solution using `Promise.all` as I suggested in the comments... If you have questions - ask...

```
export default class GetRequest extends React.Component {
  state = {
    gemBTCask: null,
    gemBTCbid: null,
    gemETHask: null,
    gemETHbid: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all([
      fetch('https://api.gemini.com/v1/pubticker/ethusd'),
      fetch('https://api.gemini.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd')
    ])
      .then(([ethResponse, btcResponse]) =>
        Promise.all([ethResponse.json(), btcResponse.json()])
      )
      .then(([ethData, btcData]) =>
        this.setState({
          gemETHask: ethData.ask,
          gemETHbid: ethData.bid,
          gemBTCask: btcData.ask,
          gemBTCbid: btcData.bid
        })
      )
      .catch(error => {
        console.error({ error });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { gemBTCask, gemBTCbid, gemETHask, gemETHbid } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="card text-center m-3">
        <div className="card-body">gemini BTC bid: $: {gemBTCbid}</div>
        <div className="card-arm">gemini BTC ask: $: {gemBTCask}</div>
        <div className="card-ear">gemini ETC bid: $: {gemETHbid}</div>
        <div className="card-leg">gemini ETC ask: $: {gemETHask}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gwkh8s?file=src%2FApp.js